How to include multiple script sources?
I have an issue that regards having multiple JavaScript srcs in one HTML file.
HTML Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Match</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesMatch.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background-color: #eaf6f6;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="myH1">Match</h1>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="stopWatch">
            00:00
        </div>
        <div id="controls">
            <button id="startBtn" onclick="start()">Start</button>
            <button id="stopBtn" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="countdown">
            30
        </div>
        <div id="controlsThirty">
            <button id="startBtnThirty" onclick="startThirty()">Start</button>
            <button id="resetBtnThirty" onclick="resetThirty()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="thirtySeconds.js"></script>
    <script src="stopwatch.js"></script>
</body>

First JavaScript code:
const display = document.getElementById("countdown");
let countdownTimer = null;
let timeLeft = 30;

function startThirty() {
    if (!countdownTimer) {
        countdownTimer = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
    }
}

function resetThirty() {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    countdownTimer = null;
    timeLeft = 30;
    display.textContent = formatTime(timeLeft);
}

function updateCountdown() {
    timeLeft--;
    display.textContent = formatTime(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        countdownTimer = null;
    }
}

function formatTime(seconds) {
    const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    return `${String(remainingSeconds).padStart(2, "0")}`;
}

Second JavaScript code:
const display = document.getElementById("stopWatch");
let timer = null;
let startTime = 0;
let elapsedTime = 0;
let isRunning = false;

function start(){
    if(!isRunning){
        startTime = Date.now() - elapsedTime;
        timer = setInterval(update, 10);
        isRunning = true;
    }
}

function stop(){
    if(isRunning){
        clearInterval(timer);
        elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
        isRunning = false;
    }
}

function update(){
    
    const currentTime = Date.now();
    elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;

    let minutes = Math.floor(elapsedTime / (1000 * 60) % 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor(elapsedTime / 1000 % 60);

    minutes = String(minutes).padStart(2, "0");
    seconds = String(seconds).padStart(2, "0");

    display.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

CSS in case anyone is wondering:
#myH1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 25%);
}
#container{
    margin-left: 700px;
    margin-right: 700px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}

#container2{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 1000px;
    margin-right: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 4px solid;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: white;
}


#stopWatch{
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.75);
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#countdown{
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.75);
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#controls button{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    min-width: 125px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#controlsThirty button{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    min-width: 125px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#startBtn{
    background-color: hsl(115, 100%, 40%);
}
#startBtn:hover{
    background-color: hsl(115, 100%, 30%);
}

#startBtnThirty{
    background-color: hsl(166, 100%, 40%);
}
#startBtnThirty:hover{
    background-color: hsl(166, 100%, 30%);
}
#stopBtn{
    background-color: hsl(10, 90%, 50%);
}
#stopBtn:hover{
    background-color: hsl(10, 90%, 40%);
}
#resetBtnThirty{
    background-color: hsl(205, 90%, 60%);
}
#resetBtnThirty:hover{
    background-color: hsl(205, 90%, 50%);
}

The issue is that when I include both JavaScript files with the <script src> tag only the first one works (in this case only functions from thirtySeconds.js work), when I swap them the other one doesn't work. Does anyone know what should I do?
I looked all over the internet, YouTube - tried stuff like defer, type="module" but nothing seemed to work.

Both scripts are setting the display variable, but to different things. This is an illustration of why global variables are bad.

Don't just change the name of one of the variables either; put it all in a namespace/object (several ways to do such things)  A number of other things could also be "better"

The old school way is to attach state as an object, var, etc. to window in a browser context, often with an IIFE. Nowadays native JS has ECMAScript Modules aka ES Modules aka ESM with export and import statements similar to how NodeJS handles modules (CommonJS format). There's also an AMD format, but that's non-standard and IDK if it support-able/ed in browsers.
